# Logging in Quarkus works in dev mode, but doesn't output in JVM docker image

Tags: java, quarkus

When building a Quarkus application, I'm running into issues where including a base application to extend causes issues with logging in JVM mode. When running in the development mode available through the Quarkus maven plugin, I am able to see logs in console and work properly with the application. When I use the JVM (or my Dockerfile to run the plugin remotely) the logs don't display in the console.

I've played around with adding explicit settings to the configurations to enable logging, which you can see in the branches below, I've made sure that packages are properly present, and even reproduced this to narrow down the cause to the base application I've authored, and this only affects when the jar is run from outside of Maven.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause the strange behaviour? I've pushed up a few cases to the publicly available app that I reproduced the issue on, along with including steps on how to reproduce the issue.

Example good case:
https://github.com/autumnfound/git-eca-rest-api/tree/malowe/master/known-good

Example with no logs in JVM:
https://github.com/autumnfound/git-eca-rest-api/tree/malowe/master/log-repro

Code that is causing the logging issue (specifically the core lib seems to be the problem child):
https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipsefdn/webdev/eclipsefdn-api-common

Commands to run in console to reproduce cases:

```sh
mvn compile quarkus:dev
mvn clean compile package  
java -jar target/git-eca-0.0.1-runner.jar
```

Exerpt from the POM to import the Jar/lib causing issues

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipsefdn</id>
            <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/eclipsefdn/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipsefoundation</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-commons</artifactId>
                <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipsefoundation</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So even with `java -jar target/git-eca-0.0.1-runner.jar` that is not running in a docker container you don't see logs?

Comment: Nope. It just holds for a moment before returning with no logs or anything else in the log. There may be some other issue present, though it should still be printing something to log if it's working in the maven env I would think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by some class loading conflict. If you'd ran the jar in debug mode:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y -jar target/git-eca-0.0.1-runner.jar
```

and connect a remote debugger to it, you could observe issues in java ServiceLoader resolution, when its trying to find service implementations for `META-INF/services/org.jboss.logging.LoggerProvider`. The JarLoader that does this, expects to find jars inside `/lib` folder with name `artifactId.jar` whereas the quarkus maven build stores them in lib folder as `group.artifactId.jar` and therefore the resource loading fails (without any logs, cause logger could not even be configured).
The root cause is that your `quarkus-core` has a transitive compile scoped dep to `jboss-logmanager`.

You can easily test a fix by excluding the offending transitive dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipsefoundation</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-core</artifactId>
    <version>${eclipse-api-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you remove that `jboss-logmanager` dependency from the pom of your `quarkus-core` module, then it will work.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Still confused as to why it worked in the quarkus:dev hot development mode, but thank you so much! The additional info for how to properly debug this is also appreciated